# How to tell applescript to record the screen with the new CMD+Shift+5 method?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to automate a screen recording of a program I created. My AppleScript opens that program resizes it and place it in the centre of the main screen. Now I want to start a recording before I manipulate the program.

I would like to start the recording with a delay, only capture the area where my program window is at and save it at a predefined location. If possible I would like to hide or minimize all other windows while the recording is running.

The main screen size and centring of the screen is done by this script:

```
set {mainScreenWidth, mainScreenHeight, mainScreenScale} to words of (do shell script "system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Main Display: Yes/{found=1} /Resolution/{width=$2; height=$4} /Retina/{scale=($2 == \"Yes\" ? 2 : 1)} /^ {8}[^ ]+/{if(found) {exit}; scale=1} END{printf \"%d %d %d\\n\", width, height, scale}'")
-- .....
set windowWidth to 1000
set windowHeight to 700
set windowPosX to round (mainScreenWidth - windowWidth) / 2 as integer
set windowPosY to round (mainScreenHeight - windowHeight) / 2 - 50 as integer

set the bounds of theWindow to {windowPosX, windowPosY, windowWidth + windowPosX, windowHeight + windowPosY}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full script that should do what you want (working off of muuvmuuv's answer above)

```
(* set properties *)
set {mainScreenWidth, mainScreenHeight, mainScreenScale} to words of (do shell script "system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Main Display: Yes/{found=1} /Resolution/{width=$2; height=$4} /Retina/{scale=($2 == \"Yes\" ? 2 : 1)} /^ {8}[^ ]+/{if(found) {exit}; scale=1} END{printf \"%d %d %d\\n\", width, height, scale}'")
set windowWidth to 1000
set windowHeight to 700
set recordedApp to "App Name"
set saveFilePath to quoted form of "/path/to/some/file.mov"
set windowMode to true -- false is full screen mode, true is window-only mode
set showCursor to true -- true value shows cursor movement, false hides it

-- length of recording in secoonds
set recordingDuration to 10

-- seconds to delay before beginning
set startDelay to 3

(* begin *)
tell application "System Events"
    (* delete old save file, otherwise capture will fail *)
    if exists saveFilePath then
        do shell script "rm -f " & saveFilePath
    end if

    (* hide other apps *)
    set procs to get (every application process whose visible is true)
    repeat with thisProc in procs
        tell thisProc
            if name is not recordedApp then
                set visible to false
            else
                set frontmost to true
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat

    (* center app window *)
    tell application process recordedApp
        tell first window
            set position to {round (mainScreenWidth - windowWidth) / 2, round (mainScreenHeight - windowHeight) / 2}
            set size to {windowWidth, windowHeight}
            set captureSize to my captureSizeString(position & size)
            log captureSize
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

set captureScript to "screencapture -v -T " & startDelay & " -V " & recordingDuration

if windowMode then
    -- window-only mode
    set captureScript to captureScript & " -R " & captureSize
else
    -- full screen mode
    set captureScript to captureScript & " -m"
end if

if showCursor then
    -- show Cursor
    set captureScript to captureScript & " -C"
end if

-- specify output file
set captureScript to captureScript & " " & saveFilePath

(* 
    this following phrase is added to detach the shell script and return its 
    process ID. The process ID can be used to refer to screencapture process
    later in the script (I've used it to set up a loop that checks to see if 
    the process is still running, so that I can run a clean-up routine). The 
    script will release the screencapture process immediately and move on to
    the next command.
    *)
set captureScript to captureScript & " &> /dev/null & echo $!"

set processID to do shell script captureScript

(* demonstration shell script *)
do shell script "say Hello -v Amelie"

(* repeat loop that tests to see if the screencapture session has ended *)
tell application "System Events"
    repeat while (first process whose unix id is processID) exists
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    my cleanUp()
end tell

on cleanUp()
    (* recording done, do clean up *)
    say "recording done"
    tell application "System Events"
        (* re-show hidden apps *)
        repeat with thisProc in procs
            tell thisProc
                set visible to true
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end cleanUp

on captureSizeString(boundsArray)
    set tid to my text item delimiters
    set my text item delimiters to ","
    set s to boundsArray as text
    set my text item delimiters to tid
    return s
end captureSizeString
```

Set the various necessary things in the 'properties' section at the top (name of the app you're recording, file path for the output, recording duration, etc), and then run it.

Set the `recordingDuration` property to a large-enough value. `screencapture` requires the parameter — it can't be set to run indefinitely — but you can end the screen recording process at any time by clicking Command-Control-Escape, so make sure the number is large enough that the process doesn't end early.

If you need to do something more complex than run a few commands after you've started `screencapture`, you'll probably want to switch this to a stay-open applet with an `idle` handler. But that's out of scope for this question.

Comment: Wow, amazing thanks! Tested it out and worked very well. Yeah the thing I miss is a start and stop command so I can tell my application to do things after the record has started. ATM it just does something -> starts recording -> waits until recording finished -> does something else. I hope Apple will add more control to screencapture in next updates. Or maybe I can find something in Python. Anyway thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you saying you want to stop and start the recording, or are you saying you want the AppleScript to be more flexible? when you say "so I can tell my application to do things" do you mean the application you're recording, or the AppleScript application that's running the recording? Be clear and specific about what you want; there's more I could do with this script than I've done here.

Comment: I would like to start and stop the recording and I mean my application not the AppleScript. The way it is ATM just lets my start the recording for a specific amount of time but while that I can not do things with my application inside the AppleScript because it waits until the recording has finished. Sorry to be unclear.

Comment: It's easy enough to write the AppleScript so that it does not wait for the screen recording to finish. What would you like the AppleScript to do after it starts the screen recording?

Comment: Run another `do shell script`. My application is a CLI a I would like to record running one command where the screencapture runs as long as the command needs to run until finished.

Comment: @muuvmuuv: made some changes; this should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way using `screencapture` command:

```
-- screencapture -R x,y,width,height -V 10 file_name
set captureOffset to 46
set captureScript to "screencapture -d -R " & windowPosX & "," & (windowPosY + captureOffset) & "," & windowWidth & "," & (windowHeight - captureOffset) & " -V 6 rec.mov"
log captureScript
do shell script captureScript
```